# Add new row into `DataGridView` and enter data from `TableAdapter` in another form

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to add new row of data in the  `DataGridView` that is located in `Form4`. The data is to be entered in the `Form3` into `TableAdapter` that is bound with `DataGridView`.

On the `Form4` I have a button that opens `Form3` and it suppose to add new rows into `DatagridView` but seems like it is not doing it.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 

Button1.Click
         Form3.Show()
         Form4.DbTableDataGridView.Rows.Add() 'this is not executed?     
         End Sub
```

On the `Form3` there is a `TableAdapter` that suppose to fill in new added rows in the `DbTableDataGridView` and then saves the changes. Something like:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form4.DbTableDataGridView.Rows.Add(Me.DbTableTableAdapter)


    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. How much skills you've got? : ) Just wondering how detailed answer you'll need? Eg. got all the sql you need? Do you specifically need to use a tableadapter? Familiar with more lowlevel stuff like SqlDataAdapter/reader

Answer (score 0):

This works fine.

```
Public Class Form4
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form3.ShowDialog()
End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form3
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form4.DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Add Something here")
End Sub
End Class
```

Does the data in your datagridview is from database?
You can have a Public Sub in your Form4 to show the records.
Example:

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection("your connection string here")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable

Public Sub ShowRecord()
    cn.Open()
    With cmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "Your command text here"
    End With
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    dt.Clear()
    da.Fill(dt)
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

In your Form3:
you can save the data in the database then call the sub in form4 like

```
form4.ShowRecord()
```

This is just a simple example though

Comment: Hi, Actually it does not answer my question at all. I know I can use a commands `Form4.DbTableDataGridView.Rows.Add("Add something here")` but I am after the bit you called "Add something here". That "Something here" has to be a specific text typed into text boxes that are created using `TableAdapter`.  I want the new added row to be filled with data from `TableAdapter` that exist in `Form3`  . Something like  `Form4.DbTableDataGridView.Rows.Add(Me.DbTableTableAdapter)` but of course it does not work.